# Pandas remove row if email exists in another df [ISSUE]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make sure that emails from df_unsub are not in prev_month. I have tried everything but it does not seem to remove the email/row from prev_month.

Here is what I have tried:

```
# Removing Unsubs, New Clients, Duplicates

#1 new_df = prev_month[~prev_month.Email.isin(unsub_list)]
#2 prev_month = prev_month.drop(prev_month[prev_month.Email.isin(unsub_list)].index.tolist())
#3 prev_month = prev_month.query("Email not in @unsub_list")
#4 prev_month = prev_month.query("Email not in @new_clients")
#5 prev_month = prev_month[~prev_month['Email'].isin(unsub_list)]

prev_month = prev_month.drop_duplicates(subset=["Email"])
```

I am receiving no errors in any other steps.

prev_month df:

```
Name Email
A.A  zys@xx.com
B.B  nn@xx.xom <<<
C.C  cc@xx.com
```

Unsub_list:

```
Name Email
G.A  ecf@xx.com
B.B  nn@xx.xom <<<
F.F  fs@xx.com
```

The desired output of prev_month:

```
Name Email
A.A  zys@xx.com
C.C  cc@xx.com
```

Comment: please provide sample inputs and expected output

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following; it should work:

```
check = prev_month['Email'].isin(unsub_list['Email'])
prev_month.drop(prev_month[check].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, so many methods tried. Finally one that works! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It's my pleasure!